# d3.mouse(this) coordinates are incorrect if outerwrapper width is fixed and if scrolled

Tags: d3.js

I need to show a tooltip on mouse over of the circle. I used `d3.mouse(this)` for getting the coordinates and assign these coordinates to the `left` and `top` style property with `position:absolute` for the `div` which makes it proper tooltip.

```
 .on('mouseover', function (d) {
    coordinates = d3.mouse(this);       
    d3.select("#tooltip")
    .style("left", coordinates[0] + padding.x + "px")
    .style("top", coordinates[1] + padding.y + "px")
    .select("#info")
    .text(tooltipText(d));
```

I have a wrapper `div` and have width and overflow property to it. When I scroll to right and hover on the circle the hover is getting displayed at other location (The coordinates of the circle on page load).

```
#outerWrapper{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 560px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

When I remove the above CSS, its working fine, but I need the outer wrapper to have fixed width.

Is there any solution to this problem.

You can find the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pushkal/4bsdbnat/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clientX` and `clientY` properties from `d3.event` object:

```
.on('mouseover', function (d) {
  d3.select("#tooltip")
    .style("left", d3.event.clientX + "px")
    .style("top", d3.event.clientY + "px")
    .select("#info")
    .text(tooltipText(d));

  d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
})
```

Check [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bsdbnat/15/).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I also found event.clientX solving the issue. What is difference between using of layerX and clientX

Comment: Yes, you are right. `clientX/clientY` is more acceptable here. I checked `layerX/layerY` it is not standard currently - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/layerX I corrected the answer and some code in my own project.